# No puedo realizar petición PUT en angular

Tags: angular, formularios, http, objeto, crud

Quiero modificar datos de un usuario desde la misma pagina, tengo un formulario y una tabla la cual se muestra solo uno a la vez, al presionar el icono de editar obtengo el id de ese usuario y ademas oculto la tabla y muestro un formulario  con todos los datos que pide la peticion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el servicio tengo el código donde le paso la interface con los datos que requiere el usuario y el id el cual será el que se modificara

```js
actualizarUsuario(_id: number, usuario: Usuario) {
  console.log("id service " + _id)
  return this.http.put(`${ this.baseUrl }/actualizar/${_id}`, usuario);
}
```

En mi componente tengo el siguiente código

Función **estado** que mando a llamar al dar click la cual me obtiene los de ese usuario

Funciona **actualizarUsuario** manda a llamar el servicio, esta función se activa al hacer el submit del formulario de actualizar, todos los datos se pueden modificar, incluso el password
Sweet alert no entra parece como si a media petición la abadonara por lo cual no muestra la alerta

```js
public actualizarForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
  if (!this.idMostrar) {
    this.cargarUsuarios();
  }

  this.actualizarForm = this.fb.group({
    _id: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Nombre: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Edad: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Ocupacion: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Genero: ['', [Validators.required]],
    Pass: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  });
}
estado(id: number): void {
  this.idMostrar = true;
  console.log(id)
  this.usuarioSeleccionado = id

}
actualizarUsuario() {
  const data = {
    ...this.actualizarForm.value,
  }
  this.usuarioService.actualizarUsuario(this.usuarioSeleccionado, data)
    .subscribe(resp => {

      console.log(resp)
    }), (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Ocurrio un error',
        text: err.error.msg,
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
      })
    }
}
```

Finalmente tengo el código html el cual muestro formulario y tabla pero con un *ngIf

```html
<div class="card" *ngIf="!idMostrar">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table full-color-table full-inverse-table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
            <th>Ocupacion</th>
            <th>Genero</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
            <td>{{usuario._id}}</td>
            <td>{{usuario.Nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{usuario.Edad}}</td>
            <td>{{usuario.Ocupacion}}</td>
            <td>{{usuario.Genero}}</td>
            <td><a (click)="estado(usuario._id)"><i class="fa fa-edit text-success"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap w100">


              <a class="cursor" data-toggle="tooltip" (click)="eliminarUsuario(usuario)" data-original-title="Borrar">
                <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i> </a>

            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="idMostrar">

  <div class="col">
    <form [formGroup]="actualizarForm" (submit)="actualizarUsuario()">

      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>_id</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="_id" placeholder="Ingrese su _id">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>Nombre</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="Nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>Edad</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="Edad" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>Ocupacion</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="Ocupacion" placeholder="Ingrese su Ocupacion">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>Genero</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="Genero" placeholder="Ingrese su Genero">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span>Password</span>
        <input class="input100" type="text" formControlName="Pass" placeholder="Ingrese su Pass">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Este es el error que me da en consola al realizar la petición es como si se quedara a medias, he pensado en poner un Delay pero aun no lo entiendo y no se como aplicarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizando pruebas el formulario al parecer no esta obteniendo los datos que yo le mando del html ya que me aparecen como vacíos todos los campos, verifique que se mande los mismos nombres y que sea el formulario y esta de forma correcta

este es la evidencia al imprimir el formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece más bien una respuesta del backend. Ya te aseguraste que no haya problemas en el controller? No tienes en angular activado algún interceptor? Al parecer el logger que tienes se dispara antes de que captures tu error en el componente.

Comment: Si, es una api desplegada en heroku y ya la profe con postman y funciona de manera correcta por eso no entiendo que es lo que falla

Comment: Afecta en algo que tenga una función  que se ejecuta en el ngOnit? esa carga los usuarios y al momento de que me pasa eso aparece la tabla no se si eso le impida terminar el proceso

Comment: Valida que en verdad mandes todos los datos desde angular, y que tu controller también los reciba completos. Puede pasar que desde postman envíes los datos correctos, pero en angular estés enviando de otra manera.

Comment: imprime el formulario y lo manda vacío pero ya cheque que las propiedades coincidan no logro entender porque se imprime vacíos

Comment: Reinicia el servidor, y agrega en el html `<pre>{{this.actualizarForm.value | json}}</pre>`  para que valides si se aplica algún cambio al interactuar con el formulario.

Comment: No me modifica nada, ya cheque que los campos coincidan, que escribiera bien el formControlName, no se que este afectado su correcto funcionamiento

Comment: El uso de el servicio `this.formBuilder` en tu caso `this.fb` esta despreciado en la versión 11 de angular. Intenta siguiendo [este ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gej2r5?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)